# How can I prevent cache on any page where a paragraph appears?

Tags: 8, caching, paragraphs

I am using the paragraphs module with a custom theme I created. I want to figure out how to clear the cache for any page that a specific paragraph appears on. The custom theme is composed of a bunch of templates (i.e. `paragraph--paragraph-name.html.twig`) and a *.theme file where I preprocess each of the paragraph types.

```
THEME_preprocess_paragraph__paragraph_name
```

I don't want to disable the entire site's cache. Can I clear the cache in this file? In this way somehow?

Comment: Exactly why do you need to clear/disable the cache there? There's a good chance that there's a better solution for whatever you are trying to do.

Comment: I created a special Paragraph to display a dynamic set of results. I grab the query string from the URL in the preprocess hook and perform the node query. When I run a different search the display is still of the previous results. If I clear cache through admin panel and run the search, the new results appear. I change the search again it displays the previous stale results.

Comment: dynamic but only based on the query argument? Then you most likely want to use a combination of cache contexts for the query URL as well as cache tags to invalidate if nodes are created/saved. I would recommend you go through https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/render-api/cacheability-of-render-arrays and the child-pages and if you have remaining questions, you can update your question

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to be really heavy handed and use \Drupal::service('page_cache_kill_switch')->trigger();

If you put that in a custom module in hook_entity_view_alter() then you can add a conditional that fires it when your paragraph entity is being built.